# Is a change in colorspace needed when comparing colors only evaluated by the computer?

Tags: opencv, color

I am confused about the need to change color space for color comparison. I have read about delta E, the Lab format, and I do understand that comparisons in the RGB color space will not seem appropriate to the human eye. However, my program uses a linear color scale to calculate velocity, from a color flow Doppler signal. It takes the mean color of a sample region and compares it to the colors of the scale to find its nearest neighbor using Euclidian distance. I do that entirely in the BGR (OpenCV) color space, as the example image below:

[image: example signal image]

Here, I obtain seemingly correct velocity values for each color circle, but is it only by chance, or **is my assumption correct that since the color comparisons take place internally, it does not matter what color space I am in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta E color difference formula is based on CIELAB color space and human perception. To convert from RGB to CIELAB space, you would need a base whitepoint (standard illuminant) which in this situation you do not have and need.

Your assumption is correct. You do not specifically need to have a color difference similar to human perception. Additionally color distance metric should be based on your needs (you can use weighting depending on your needs).